# Add success message for built-in LoginView of Django

Tags: python, django

I am using built-in `LoginView` from `django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView` and I don't know how to send a success message upon a successful login of user. Here is how `urls.py` looks like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    ...
]
```

well, you know every other thing is abstract away and works magically as expected.
How do I override this `LoginView` to add `success_message`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin

class LoginFormView(SuccessMessageMixin, LoginView):
    template_name = 'auth/login.html'
    success_url = '/success_url/'
    success_message = "You were successfully logged in."
```

And in the urls

```
path('login/', LoginFormView.as_view(), name='login'),
```